# SQL WHERE IN (...) sort by order of the list?

Tags: sql, sorting, where-clause

Let's say I have query a database with a where clause

```
WHERE _id IN (5,6,424,2)
```

Is there any way for the returned cursor to be sorted in the order that the _id's where listed in the list? _id attribute from first to last in Cursor to be 5, 6, 424, 2?

This happens to be on Android through a ContentProvider, but that's probably not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select ID list using subquery and join with it:

```
select t1.*
from t1
inner join
(
  select 1 as id, 1 as num
  union all select 5, 2
  union all select 3, 3
) ids on t1.id = ids.id
order by ids.num
```

**UPD:** Code fixed

Comment: I think you need 2 columns in your inner table.  The ID as you have it and a further sequence column.  Then order by sequence.

Comment: Oops.. Yes, sure. It was my misstype.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to do separate SQL queries with a UNION between each. You would obviously issue each query in the order you would like it returned to you.

Answer (score 1):

...
order by
 case when _id=5 then 1
      when _id=6 then 2
 end

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can join it to a virtual table that contains the list required in sort order

```
select tbl.*
from tbl
inner join (
    select 1 as sorter, 5 as value union all
    select 2, 6 union all
    select 3, 424 union all
    select 4, 2) X on tbl._id = X.value
ORDER BY X.sorter
```

Comment: The `virtual table` could be a CTE (easier to read, IMO) or even a base table. Standard SQL doesn't allow correlation names in the `ORDER BY` clause, meaning the `sorter` column would need to be included in the `SELECT` clause, which is no bad thing because it's good practise to expose the 'sorter' column to the caller anyhow.

Comment: @onedaywhen this should work in SQLite, SQL Server, Sybase, MySQL and PostgreSQL. CTE does not work for 4 of them, MSSQL pre-2005, nor Oracle without "from dual". The question was generically "sql". It's Android so I rather suspect it is not MSSQL

Comment: When I see just the 'sql' tag I tend to think in terms of Standard SQL and CTE's are in the Standards (and postgre, BTW). It doesn't have to mean that all the popular SQL products support it ;)

Answer (score 1):

List? You don't have a list! ;)

This:

```
WHERE _id IN (5,6,424,2)
```

is mere syntactic sugar for this:

```
WHERE (
       _id  = 5
       OR _id = 6
       OR _id = 424
       OR _id = 2
      )
```

SQL has but one data structure, being the table. Your `(5,6,424,2)` isn't a table either! :)

You could create a table of values but your next problem is that tables do not have any logical ordering. Therefore, as per @cyberkiwi's answer, you'd have to create a column explicitly to model the sort order. And in order to make it explicit to the calling application, ensure you expose this column in the `SELECT` clause of your query.