# php + mysql two table sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

```
+------------------------------------+
 | uid       | user_name   | food   |
 +-----------------------------------+
 | 12345     | Joe         | 3,1,2   |
 | 12346     | John        | 2,1     |
 | 12347     | David       | 30,2,1  |
 | 12355     | Peter       | 50,1    |
 +-----------------------------------+


+-------------------------+
 | food_id  | food_name   |
 +------------------------+
 | 1        | apple       |
 | 2        | orange      |
 | 3        | banana      |
 | 50       | pear        |
 +------------------------+

$user_sql = "SELECT `uid`,`user_name`,`food` FROM `user`";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($user_sql);
$stmt->execute();
$user_data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$food_id = $user_data["food"]; // will be get eg: 50,1,3
$food_sql = "SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE `food_id` in ($food_id)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($food_sql);
$stmt->execute();
$food_data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I will be foreach $food_data.

That's OK, can show it.

But this array($food_data) is sorting order by `food`.`food_id`, I need sort same to `user`.`food`

**EG show:**

Joe   - apple,orange,banana   (default sort by food_id 1,2,3)

John  - apple,orange  (default sort by food_id 1,2)

David - apple,orange,pear  (default sort by food_id 1,2,50)

Peter - apple,pear  (default sort by food_id 1,50)

but I need change it.

**How to change to**

Joe   - banana,apple,orange  (sort same to `user`.`food` field value 3,1,2)

John  - orange,apple  (sort same to `user`.`food` field value 2,1)

David - pear,orange,apple  (sort same to `user`.`food` field value 30,2,1)

Peter - pear,apple   (sort same to `user`.`food` field value 50,1)

**I had try one by one select sql through the smarty template plugin.**

But that's so wasted resources. I can do something in php or mysql?

---

Comment: add `ORDER BY food_id DESC` at the end of your query

Comment: There're many ways to achieve what you want, but it seems, that here's what are you asking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858828/sql-where-in-sort-by-order-of-the-list.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data

Comment: so you suggest I merge the two sql statements to one statement?

Comment: you want like this SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE id in (2,3,1) ORDER BY FIELD(id,3,2,1) ?

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya ORDER BY FIELD(id,2,3,1)

Comment: @Sky yes .. you can use ORDER BY FIELD to order whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code like

```
SELECT * FROM `food` WHERE `food_id` in (3,1,2) ORDER BY FIELD(food_id,3,1,2)
```

to achieve "Joe - banana,apple,orange (sort same to user.food field value 3,1,2)"
same for others... you can use ORDER BY FIELD to order whatever you want

Comment: It's so convenient. This is what I wanted. I got it. Thanks so much BrijalSavaliya.

Answer (score 1):

The smart way would be to have a separate user_food table with uid, food_id pairs instead of storing the food_ids in a single field in a comma separated string. In this case the query would be simple using [group_concat() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
select u.uid, u.user_name, group_concat(f.food_name order by f.food_id) as food_name
from user u
left join user_food uf on u.uid=uf.uid
left join food f on uf.food_id=f.food_id
group by u.uid, u.user_name
```

The quick way is to join the 2 tables using [find_in_set() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), and use the group_concat() again:

```
select u.uid, u.user_name, group_concat(f.food_name order by f.food_id) as food_name
from user u
left join food f on find_in_set(f.food_id,u.food)>0
group by u.uid, u.user_name
```

Comment: @spencer7593 you are welcomed to make the same comment (without reference to order by). I checked, it's not the same OP.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. I got it. You let me I learned a new statement